# jQuery search/filter a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a search using jQuery to filter job listings on a page based on the titles.

Here is my jQuery

```
function quickSearch() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("quicksearch");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("jobResults");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("h2")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my search field

```
<input type="text" id="quicksearch" onkeyup="quickSearch()" placeholder="Search jobs from Reed, Skills People Group & Glenigan" title="Search jobs from Reed, Skills People Group & Glenigan">
```

here is the list of jobs im trying to search and filter

```
<ul class="kamkaaj-row sort-list grid" id="jobResults" style="position: relative; height: 15684px;">
    <li class="kamkaaj-column-12 sort-item Reed jobResult Sheffield" id="jobResult" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
        <div class="kamkaaj-tabwrap">
            <div class="kamkaaj-tabro">
                <div class="kamkaaj-tabce">
                    <figure>
                        <a href="https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/technical-sales-engineer-construction-engineering/39044835" target="_blank"><img src="/themes/skills-academy/assets/images/reed-min.jpg" alt="Reed Jobs in Sheffield"></a>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div class="kamkaaj-tabce">
                    <div class="kamkaaj-job-listing-text">
                        <h2>
                        <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#job39044835" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Technical Sales Engineer Construction / Engineering</a>
                                                        </h2>
                        <ul class="kamkaaj-job-listing-options">
                            <li>Sheffield</li>
                            <li>Full-time</li>
                            <li>£35000 - £35000 <small>Per Annum</small></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="kamkaaj-tabce">
                    <time datetime="2008-02-14 20:00" id="daysSince">
                    </time>
                    <ul class="kamkaaj-job-listing-savelist">
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/technical-sales-engineer-construction-engineering/39044835" class="kamkaaj-job-listing-savelist-btn" target="_blank">View</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="kamkaaj-color">Reed</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="kamkaaj-column-12 sort-item Reed jobResult Sheffield" id="jobResult" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 154px;">
        <div class="kamkaaj-tabwrap">
            <div class="kamkaaj-tabro">
                <div class="kamkaaj-tabce">
                    <figure>
                        <a href="https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/construction-solicitor/38973615" target="_blank"><img src="/themes/skills-academy/assets/images/reed-min.jpg" alt="Reed Jobs in Sheffield"></a>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div class="kamkaaj-tabce">
                    <div class="kamkaaj-job-listing-text">
                        <h2>
                         <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#job38973615" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Construction Solicitor</a>
                        </h2>
                        <ul class="kamkaaj-job-listing-options">
                            <li>Sheffield</li>
                            <li>Full-time</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="kamkaaj-tabce">
                    <time datetime="2008-02-14 20:00" id="daysSince">
                    </time>
                    <ul class="kamkaaj-job-listing-savelist">
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/construction-solicitor/38973615" class="kamkaaj-job-listing-savelist-btn" target="_blank">View</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="kamkaaj-color">Reed</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

For some reason its not working.

I have based what I am doing on the W3Schools version which can be found here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

My version which isn't working can be found here:
https://sheffieldskillsacademy.com/locations/sheffield/jobs

Any help to fix it would be appreciated.

Comment: Immediately upon loading your page the console shows several errors.  That's probably where you should start.  "It's not working" doesn't really describe the problem much, but since you're getting specific error messages then it sounds like you have some additional work to do first.

Comment: also, quickSearch of what? in your function you don't provide any argument. Another point, you are not using jquery, you are just using plain javascript and please have a look at filter/map/reduce Array methods. If you have any problems with "oh but I can't use these methods in a NodeList", just use Array.from or something like that.

Comment: @David what I mean is that when I type in the search field the job listings are not filtering as expected. I.e if I type a query and a listing contains that query it shows whilst all listings not containing that query are hidden. I have fixed most of the errors in console now but the search code still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at Javascript's built-in [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/filter) function. Might come in handy for this problem.

Errors on your website show, that while executing this line

```
 txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
```

a is undefined. Array that you're iterating over does not contain what you expect it does. Most of your li elements don't even have a h2 element inside of them, that's what causes some of the errors. That's where I'd begin searching, since you might have misunderstood your own DOM structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor the code to select only the search elements using `querySelectorAll('li ul li')`

```js
function quickSearch(input) {
  var filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("jobResults");
  li = ul.querySelectorAll('li ul li');
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    txtValue = li[i].textContent || li[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="quicksearch" onkeyup="quickSearch(this)" placeholder="Search jobs from Reed, Skills People Group & Glenigan" title="Search jobs from Reed, Skills People Group & Glenigan">


<ul class="kamkaaj-row sort-list grid" id="jobResults" style="position: relative; height: 15684px;">
  <li class="kamkaaj-column-12 sort-item Reed jobResult Sheffield" id="jobResult" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <div class="kamkaaj-tabwrap">
      <div class="kamkaaj-tabro">
        <div class="kamkaaj-tabce">
          <figure>
            <a href="https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/technical-sales-engineer-construction-engineering/39044835" target="_blank"><img src="/themes/skills-academy/assets/images/reed-min.jpg" alt="Reed Jobs in Sheffield"></a>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="kamkaaj-tabce">
          <div class="kamkaaj-job-listing-text">
            <h2>
              <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#job39044835" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Technical Sales Engineer Construction / Engineering</a>
            </h2>
            <ul class="kamkaaj-job-listing-options">
              <li>Sheffield</li>
              <li>Full-time</li>
              <li>£35000 - £35000 <small>Per Annum</small></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="kamkaaj-tabce">
          <time datetime="2008-02-14 20:00" id="daysSince">
                    </time>
          <ul class="kamkaaj-job-listing-savelist">
            <li>
              <a href="https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/technical-sales-engineer-construction-engineering/39044835" class="kamkaaj-job-listing-savelist-btn" target="_blank">View</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="kamkaaj-color">Reed</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="kamkaaj-column-12 sort-item Reed jobResult Sheffield" id="jobResult" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 154px;">
    <div class="kamkaaj-tabwrap">
      <div class="kamkaaj-tabro">
        <div class="kamkaaj-tabce">
          <figure>
            <a href="https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/construction-solicitor/38973615" target="_blank"><img src="/themes/skills-academy/assets/images/reed-min.jpg" alt="Reed Jobs in Sheffield"></a>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="kamkaaj-tabce">
          <div class="kamkaaj-job-listing-text">
            <h2>
              <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#job38973615" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Construction Solicitor</a>
            </h2>
            <ul class="kamkaaj-job-listing-options">
              <li>Sheffield</li>
              <li>Full-time</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="kamkaaj-tabce">
          <time datetime="2008-02-14 20:00" id="daysSince">
                    </time>
          <ul class="kamkaaj-job-listing-savelist">
            <li>
              <a href="https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/construction-solicitor/38973615" class="kamkaaj-job-listing-savelist-btn" target="_blank">View</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="kamkaaj-color">Reed</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```